# How to configure the package.json to install the local package first, and then try to install it from the registry or repository?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

Is there any way to configure the `npm install` process in the `package.json` to try installing a new package from local source first and if it's none then try to install it from another place?

Yeah, I know this is [syntax for versions](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies), but I need something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ui-elements": "file:path/to/ui-elements || git+https://user@bitbucket.org/user/ui-elements.git"
}
```

The reason why I need behavior like this, because I have a package that contains some UI elements, that used across different React applications. These UI elements in active development and that's why I need a local copy of it. Finally, these applications will be deployed on AWS clouds and Docker will try to install dependencies and it would be greate if in one config file I can install dependencies from the repository if this package doesn't exist locally.

And also I know about `npm link`, but this will be annoying to manually execute this command in a bunch of directories, and run `npm link` every time on a new environment or local machine in a specific way. This is not about portability. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works perfectly for my needs. I decided to use the [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples) hook to run a custom script just after all packages are installed. Then I declared a custom property `localDependencies` in `package.json`.

That's how it looks in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "node install.js"
},
"localDependencies": {
  "ui-elements": "file:path/to/ui-elements"
},
"dependencies": {
  "ui-elements": "git+https://user@bitbucket.org/user/ui-elements.git"
}
```

As for the file `install.js`, I've tried several solutions to get it done. First I've tried to use `npm.commands.install(dependencies)` from the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) package. This `install()` method working fine, but here the problem, this method also overwrite my **dependencies** list using dependencies from **localDependencies** in `package.json`. I've tried to find a way to pass `--no-save` parameter to the `install` method, but it didn't work at all. And overall this API's not documented anywhere (or I couldn't find it). That's why I decided to use an `exec` function from `child_process` and run `npm` command directly.

`install.js`:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && packageJson.localDependencies) {
  Object.values(packageJson.localDependencies).forEach((path) => {
    exec(`npm install ${path} --no-save`).stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
  });
}
```

Well, what we have in the end?

For production, we need to `export NODE_ENV='production'` to global variables, and after that `install.js` will be ignored and everything will work as usual.

For local development, we need only a valid path to the package for `localDependencies`. After `npm install` the script from `postinstall` just re-install new packages from local storage.

There is only one downside, `postinstall` will rewrite already existing downloaded package.